# Two situations regarding Declaring / Releasing IplImages

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I do care a lot about the memory in my project. It has crashed before due to memory leak.
I'm thinking of two approaches:

- Declaring the different IplImages just once in the main project part.
- Declaring everytime as soon as I need to declare an IplImage and release it just when I don't need it anymore.

Supposing that I'm having a realtime project, and thus, the IplImages are always overwritten to generate new ones, and using the following lines for declaration / release:

```
IplImage*image=cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
cvReleaseImage(&image);
```

What would be the best way to optimize the use of memory?

Comment: You could consider using the C++ interface (since you tagged this question as C++ and not C), and let the releasing be done automatically.

Comment: Why do you say "`IplImages` are always overwritten to generate new ones" ? Your `IplImages` can be overwritten without generating a new one each time.

Comment: @zakinster That's it, they are overwritten without generating a new IPLIMAGE on each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also to have one IplImage pointer, then use cvCreateImageHeader to fill the header and cvSetData to fill image data from buffer every time. At the end you can use cvReleaseImageHeader to release it.

```
IplImage *m_img_show = NULL;
CvSize cv_img_size = cvSize(m_width,m_height);
m_img_show = cvCreateImageHeader(cv_img_size, IPL_DEPTH_8U,3);
```

Use this every time to fill image from m_pBuffer.

```
cvSetData(m_img_show, m_pBuffer, m_width*3);
```

At the end release the header and image data buffer

```
cvReleaseImageHeader(&m_img_show);
```

Comment: Note that `cvReleaseImageHeader` won't release the data, you'll still have to manually release `m_pBuffer`.

Comment: What's the point of using an external buffer ? Do you intend to do the image processing directly on the `m_pBuffer` ?

Answer (score 2):

*Regarding the memory management issue,*

If you want to stay with the C-interface, you could use `cv::Ptr<_Tp>` which is similar to c++11 `shared_ptr` :

```
cv::Ptr<IplImage> image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

Your image will automatically be released as soon as the `image` pointer is destroyed thanks to the `Ptr<IplImage>` destructor :

```
template<> inline Ptr<IplImage>::delete_obj() {
    cvReleaseImage(&obj);
}
```

Note that you could use the C++ interface of OpenCV (`cv::Mat` instead of `cv::IplImage` as instance) which has built-in memory management :

```
cv::Mat image(Size(640, 480), CV_8UC1);
```

*Regarding the memory usage optimization*,

You could use `cvCreateImageHeader`, `cvSetData` and `cvReleaseImageHeader` as suggested to create an `IplImage` out of a `void*` buffer without reallocating a whole `IplImage`, but I don't really see the point except if you're doing your image processing outside OpenCV.

Using OpenCV, **You don't have to create a new `IplImage` at each processing step**. You can use the same `IplImage` as source **and** destination for any in-place algorithm, and you can always reuse the same temporary buffer for any other algorithm.